# Converting from Hg to git, taking opportunity to edit history

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

So I have a Mercurial repository that I want to convert to git, nothing special there, I know how do that, fast-export as explained [here](http://www.wordsinboxes.com/2012/02/migrating-repositories-from-bitbucket.html) is a brilliant tool for that.

What I want to do, is take this opportunity to correct the endless annoying typos that I have slipped into the commit messages in my Mercurial repository. Does anybody know of a tool, or how to get fast-export, that will let me do this.

I assume something that can export a list of change sets along with the commit messages that I can 'correct' that can then be fed back into a tool would work, as I assume that basically all fast-export does is manually work through your commits anyway.

Once again, I do not *just* want to move from Hg to git, I *also* want to edit the commit messages.

Comment: As a fallback you always can move and then correct.

Comment: @kirelagin care to answer explaining how I can edit git commit history?

Comment: Here is a [nice article](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html). I think the most appropriate way in your case is doing an interactive rebase with `reword` action (this manual is a bit outdated, it tells you to choose `edit` and then do `commit --amend`, but in recent versions of git `reword` is a shortcut for doing this).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I had a look at the `histedit` and sure, it would probably do the job, but turns out git has the functionality I want built in.

I used the fast-export to convert my Mecurial repository to Git, then used `git rebase -i HEAD~14` (14 being the number of commits I had). This let me chose which commits I want to just take as given, which I want to edit the comments for etc. The [online git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) does a good job of explaining this tool.

Sadly this did not let me edit the very first commit message, but I can live with that  one typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [histedit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) to modify the hg repository before converting it.

Comment: ah, the [readme](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/histedit/src/tip/README) seems to detail a bit ore about how to edit the commit messages

Comment: At the bottom of the link there's an example of usage. Replace "pick" with "edit" in the editor that pops open and you'll get to edit commit messages. You'll have to run `hg histedit --continue` after it drops you back to the shell.